# visual studio 2012 .net frame work compatability

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Can you please help me with this. Am I able to run .net 2.0 in visual studio 2012? Can you direct me to the diagrams that show the framework compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are able to build **.Net v2.0** projects in the [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).

Here goes the list of all available versions of .Net Framework:

http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/uWRTNBl.png

Answer (score 1):

> Framework targeting does not guarantee that your application will run correctly. You must test your application to make sure it runs against the targeted version. You cannot target framework versions that are earlier than the .NET Framework 2.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197(v=vs.110).aspx

In short, yes, you can target .NET 2.0 - and no, there's no master list of compatibility issues.